# spring boot unable to connect to my postgresql aws rds database

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds

i had configured my spring boot 3.0.5 application to access to my database aws rds but i have a connection error. my database has private access and i use a ssh connection whith ec2 instance to access in my databese whith pgadmin.

my application properties config

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://endpoindofmydatabase:5432/db_name
spring.datasource.username=user_name
spring.datasource.password=user_password
#information jpa
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect

server.port=9090
```

the error that i have

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: La tentative de connexion a échoué.
    ...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
...
```

i verified the credential but i didn't saw any problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to add data to the environment variables for the test...